# Svelte application bug: global.css overwrites component-level CSS

Tags: javascript, css, svelte

In a Svelte app, I have a form with simple validation.

### The form

```
<form id="surveyForm" class="mt-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-full" on:click={Continue}>Continue</button>
</form>
```

### The validation:

```
import {fly, fade} from 'svelte/transition';
let hasError = false;
let errMessage = "";
let isSuccessVisible = false;

function validateInput() {
    var surveyForm = document.getElementById('surveyForm'),
        inputFields = surveyForm.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]');

    hasError = false;

    inputFields.forEach(function(field) {
        field.classList.remove("is-invalid");
        var inputFieldVal = field.value;
        if (inputFieldVal.length == 0) {
            field.classList.add("is-invalid");
            hasError = true;
        }
    });
    errMessage = "All the fileds are mandatory";
}


function Continue(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    validateInput();
    if (hasError == false) {
        isSuccessVisible = true;

        setTimeout(function() {
            isSuccessVisible = false;
        }, 3000);
    }
}
```

In order to give invalid form fields a red border, I use `border: 1px solid #c00 !important`:

```
.error-alert {
    border: 1px solid #c00 !important;
    color: #c00;
}
```

The class `is-invalid` is correctly added (and removed), yet, the default `global.css` styles *overwrite my component-level styles*, as you can see in this **[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/52b9346e1c4d4e6ea7f1252c8ec71f21?version=3.24.0)**.

Why does this happen? What is a reliable fix?

---

**NOTE:** The case described is a simplified one, in reality I might need other validations, like making sure the value is numeric. The solution I have to implement is not a very *specific* one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the technique Rich described for other validations by using HTML5 client-side form validation.  More information can be found on the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation)

```
<form id="surveyForm" class="mt-4" class:submitted>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First name" required>
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name" required>
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter a number" required>
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required>
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="Date" required>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-full" on:click|preventDefault={Continue}>Continue</button>
</form>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/fa489a808bf24bf98ad2ef87b1ffec7b?version=3.24.0)

If you don't want to use this - or it doesn't cover all your use cases for some reason - you can manipulate the classes using Svelte instead of accessing the DOM directly:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input bind:value={second} type="text" class="form-control" class:is-invalid="{ submitted && second.length == 0 }" placeholder="Last name">
</div>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/0d430f4f393c44eaa0648216957f21e7?version=3.24.0)

The reason Svelte removes your `.is-invalid` style is because Svelte doesn't use it.  I wouldn't recommend it in this case but you can force Svelte to keep the style using `:global()`:

```
:global(.is-invalid) {
    border: 1px solid #c00;
}
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/aaf93f5e63e34356b666e57429863225?version=3.24.0)

Answer (score 5):

In the REPL, you see the following warning:

> Unused CSS selector (87:1)

That's because the `.is-invalid` selector isn't used anywhere in the markup — if a classname is unused, Svelte tells you about it and removes it. For Svelte to be able to 'see' it, it has to be in the markup — you can't add it programmatically with `classList`. (This is a feature, not a bug: programmatically manipulating the DOM will inevitably lead to your view getting out of sync with your state.)

In this case though, you don't need to add a class to the input element, or do the checking inside a function. You can just use the input's `required` attribute and `:invalid` CSS selector:

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First name" required>
```

```css
input:invalid {
  border: 1px solid #c00;
}
```

The `:invalid` state will be applied before the user submits any data though, so you may want to add a class that indicates whether the user has tried to submit already:

```html
<form id="surveyForm" class="mt-4" class:submitted>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First name" required>
  </div>

  <!-- ... -->
</form>
```

```css
.submitted input:invalid {
  border: 1px solid #c00;
}
```

The easiest way to add that class is in a `click` event handler on the button.

[Here's a demo](https://svelte.dev/repl/5230b1d71f1b4b048cf05e3a7a49aefc?version=3.24.0).

Using the stuff you get for free in HTML comes with other benefits. For example, the form won't submit as long as there are validation errors (and validation isn't limited to 'required' — you can mandate specific patterns, or use e.g. `type="email"` to require a valid email address, etc), which means that inside your `submit` event handler, you already know that the inputs are valid.

Comment: Thank you for this reminder to leverage HTML whenever possible, something I'm guilty of overlooking too often. I've taken the liberty to modify your REPL ever so slightly in order to bring back the global error/success alert: https://svelte.dev/repl/70bb412acad94c3ab4bc54e5bb3da312?version=3.24.0

Comment: Nice, but what if I need other validations, like making sure the value is numeric, for instance?

Comment: @RazvanZamfir, then you would give the input a type of `number`, or use a css selector in combination with `not()` to add extra styles in that case.